# Sqlalchemy with cx_Oracle query only returns one result

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy, cx-oracle

I am trying to query an Oracle DB table from sqlalchemy with

```
session.query(PAY).filter_by(REGION_CODE=record['REGION_CODE'],
                             AOID=record['AOID'],
                             COMPANY_CODE=record['COMPANY_CODE']).all()
```

it returns 1 value, however if do a raw sql

```
select * from schema.table_name where REGION_CODE = '{record['REGION_CODE']}' 
and AOID = '{record['AOID']}' and COMPANY_CODE = '{record['COMPANY_CODE']}
```

The database has 2 records I get two results. The results have identical values but are 2 different records.

Any one have any idea why the query only returns the single value?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that SQLAlchemy is prepending a "distinct" clause to the query which will eliminate duplicate rows. You can find out for sure by setting the environment variable `DPI_DEBUG_LEVEL` to the value `16` before running the two examples. This will show the SQL statements that are being executed and you can confirm my suspicions!

Comment: Its not and if I add echo = True, I see its good sql. The only other issues is that there are no primary keys in this table